# Como mostrar la lista de seleccion de certificados de cliente al pulsar un boton .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, iis

Hola he visto que hay páginas que muestran la lista de certificados de cliente no al entrar en una página que los solicite, sino mas tarde, cuando el usuario ya ha entrado en la página y pulsa un botón. 
Yo normalmente establezco en IIS esta configuración y el navegador lo solicita por si mismo.
¿Sabéis como configurar IIS o que código se necesita para que el navegador muestre esta lista no automáticamente al entrar en la página sino al pulsar un botón dentro de la misma?

Answer (score 1):

desde el backend no lo puedes hacer , si quieres uno de los certificados del cliente, este debe enviártelos como parte del request.

Y no se puede porque no sería una llamada segura tratar de acceder a los certificados de un usuario sin su consentimiento.

Comment: No estoy totalmente de acuerdo con esto ya que si bien parte de tu concepto es cierto, he visto paginas que lo hacen. Por ejemplo cualquier pagina de la administración que use la pasarela de autenticación Cl@ve donde en la propia pagina puedes dar un boton y entonces te pide el certificado de cliente. Como? Eso es lo que quiero yo saber.

Comment: Exacto pide un certificado del cliente y el cliente lo selecciona o carga por si mismo.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero precisamente yo me refiero a ese paso, ¿como mostrar la lista de los certificados de cliente al pulsar un boton? Luego el ya seleccionará el que quiera y lo envia por supuesto. Esto por lo que yo se lo gestionas en IIS en una pagina poniendo require certificate, y lo solicita en navegador antes de cargar la pagina, pero yo deseo que no sea en ese momento de carga sino al pulsar un boton de esa pagina se muestre la lista de certificados.